# Problem with differentials?

Tags: calculus, soft-question

What I don't get is why can we cancel and multiply out differentials if differentials are not considered numbers. Delta x is not the same as dx, but it's intuitive to multiply and divide by delta x, but how does this work with differentials?

I don't find the chain rule logical at all.

Comment: $dx/dt$ is just a symbol. You are not dividing by $dt$.

Comment: Then what are we dividing/multiplying by in the chain rule?

Comment: Chain rule says that the derivative of a composite function at some point $t_0$ is the product of the derivative of the first function at $t_0$ with the derivative of the second function at the image of $t_0$ by the first function. Uff! In symbols: $(f\circ g)'(t_0)=g'(t_0)f'(g(t_0))$.

Comment: may also want to have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis#Basic_definitions

Comment: Leibniz, the inventor of $d/dt$ was aware that his symbol was not a fraction, but *it behaves* like a fraction in many cases.  Just ingeniuos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $df/dx$ actually makes sense in the context of differential forms. Say you have a 1-dimensional real manifold with the coordinate function $x$ and a function $f(x)$ defined on it. Also you have the coordinate vector field $\partial_x$ which already spans all vector fields on the manifold as $v=v(x)\partial_x$.

The definition of the differential $df$ is that it is a function that maps a vector field $v$ to the derivative of $f$ in direction of the vector field. Or more formally $$df(v) = vf$$ which in our case is for all possible vector fields $$df(v(x)\partial_x)=v(x)\partial_x f(x)$$

The same way we can evaluate the coordinate differential $dx$ to be $$dx(v(x)\partial_x)=v(x)\partial_x x=v(x)$$

With these you can actually look at the quotient of the differentials $$\frac{df(v(x)\partial_x)}{dx(v(x)\partial_x)} = \frac{v(x)\partial_x f(x)}{v(x)}$$

which to make sense as a differential quotient has to be independent of the actual vector field. And as you can see the $v(x)$ actually cancels (and in such a way that we can fix the removable singularities of $\frac{v(x)}{v(x)}$ for $v(x)=0$) and we can get rid of the argument and just write $$\frac{df}{dx}=\partial_x f(x) = f'(x)$$

This is how differential forms make sense of the intuitive way to handle differentials.